# MIPS multiplication via addition

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm currently using QtSpim for a MIPS program. The objective is to use addition to multiply. This is my code which is relatively straightforward:

```
.data
inputX: .word 5
inputY: .word 4
tempX: .word 0
constantOne: .word 1
finalX: .word 0

.text
main:

lw $t1, inputX
lw $t2, inputY
lw $t0, tempX
lw $t3, constantOne
lw $t4, finalX
beq $t2, $zero, Exit #when Y equals zero, X is already zero so exits.
Loop: beq $t2, $t3, yIsOne #when y is one skip rest of loop
add $t0, $t1, $t1 #actual "multiplication".
sub $t2, $t2, $t3 #what makes loop continue
bne $t2, $zero, Loop #while Y isnt yet 0.
yIsOne: add $t0, $t0, $t1 #adds X to 0 or the multiplied Xs
Exit:
sw $t4, finalX
```

When I run the program, I get this:

```
R8  [t0] = f
R9  [t1] = 5
R10 [t2] = 1
R11 [t3] = 1
R12 [t4] = 0
```

which was very baffling so I went through single-step and the first time t0 should've had 5 added to its total, it became a. It stayed that way until after my yIsOne jump, which is where it became f. Everything else appears to work fine. It jumps back up for the loop correctly. t2 gets subtracted by one every time. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
add $t0, $t1, $t1 #actual "multiplication". t0 = t1+t1
```

I think it should be:

```
add $t0, $t0, $t1 #actual "multiplication". t0 += t1
```

Because you want add value to tempX evry loop, not assign new value (inputX +inputX).

Comment: good point. I changed it. After the first iteration, t0 becomes 5. After the second, it becomes a. Then f. Then 14. Progression, but not quite working. Maybe there's something wrong with my version of qtSpim or something. :/

Comment: 4*5 = 14 (hex) = 20 (dec)

Comment: awesome. Is there a way to get the decimal answer instead of hex?

Comment: First time i see this simulator but option "registers -> decimal" working as you need.